# Does Android's requestLocationUpdate() with a minDistance conserve any battery?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I've successfully used the Android [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) with the minTime and the minDistance parameters. I'm trying to understand the impact of minDistance on battery usage.

**If minDistance is used, is the geolocation (e.g. GPS) continuously being polled to see if minDistance is exceeded?**

The Android docs say:

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime
>   milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location
>   providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime
>   should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

How can the minDistance parameter be used unless the user's geolocation is continuously being polled? It seems like the Android service cannot perform any power-conserving optimization using this parameter.

Answer (score -1):

It's a question of quality. If you only request updates after 100 meters, your gps does not need to run with full resolution. Depending on the driver and supplier, that might save energy. Android offeres a possibility. Whether it is used depends on the gps supplier and the app developer.

Comment: a GPS chip always run on full resolution. there is no chip that can save energy if you only want every 100m. things may be different if you use every 5 km and using GSM cell locating